# Proving or disproving, that a sequence is Cauchy

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm in the middle of an assignment trying to prove/disprove that something is a Cauchy sequence . Here is where I am, my problem is, that I can't really seem to limit my distance by a epsilon, probably because it is not Cauchy. I tried $\epsilon = 1/n $ and $ \epsilon = \sqrt{1/n} $

Problem: Is $ f_{n, n \in \mathbb{N}} $  Cauchy in $ \mathcal{M} $

$ f_n (x) = \sqrt{x-a + 1/n} $ $ x \in [a,b]$

$ \mathcal{M} = (C^1, ||\cdot||) $

||f|| = $ ||f||_u + ||f'||_u $
 I've already shown that $ ||f||_u $ is limited by a epsilon so i'm only looking at $ ||f'||_u $

$ sup(|  \frac{1}{ 2 \sqrt{x-a  + \frac{1}{n} } } - \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x-a + \frac{1}{m} } }  |)  ) $

Then I choose sup as x=a

$  | \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}} - \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{m}}} | $

And here is the problem, is it possible to limit this, I don't think so but an argument would be nice. Thanks

Comment: You "chose the $\;\sup\;$ as $\;x=a\;"$ ? You can't do that: you *must* either prove the supremum happens when $\;x=a\;$ , or else leave it open.

Comment: Isn't it right since both fractions is positive number, so i want to maximise the values of them, to find the sup? Not a prove but thought it was true